# How to forward psql shell from kubectl

Tags: bash, postgresql, kubernetes, psql, kubectl

I'm trying to make my life easier and am coding a bash script. One of these allows me to kube into a pod with postgres access, get the credentials I need, and run the interactive psql shell.

However, upon running

```
kubectl <flags> exec $podname -- bash -c ' get_credentials && psql <psql args> -i -t
```

the terminal hangs.

I can't directly connect to the database, and the process to get the credentials is kinda cumbersome. Is there some bash concept I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 2):

> `kubectl <flags> exec $podname`

That `exec` is missing its `-i` and `-t` for `--stdin=true` and `--tty=true` to describe to kubernetes that you wish your terminal and the remote terminal to be associated with one another:

`kubectl exec -it $podname -- etc etc`

If you are intending the `-i` and `-t` present at the end of your cited example above to be passed to `exec`, be aware that the double dashes *explicitly* switch off argument parsing from `kubectl`, so there is no way it will see them